# Application unavailable for non-developer

Tags: facebook-apps

My application is now finished, so to put it online I disabled 'sandbox mode' in application's page. But it's not working, if i'm logged as developer i can run the application, else i get a 404 error... Facebook told me it could take several minutes, but i disabled 'sandbox mode' at 11am !! Does Facebook need to validate my app?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? (and are your secure and non-secure URLs both correct?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution :
we can't use header('location:xxx.php') for asking app authorization, (because $loginUrl is null) it must be like this :

```
try {
    // On récupère l'UID de l'utilisateur Facebook courant
    // On récupère les infos de base de l'utilisateur
    $me = $fb->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

    // S'il y'a un problème lors de la récup, perte de session entre temps, suppression des autorisations...

    // On récupère l'URL sur laquelle on devra rediriger l'utilisateur pour le réidentifier sur l'application
    $loginUrl = $fb->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'canvas'    => 1,
            'fbconnect' => 0,
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.facebook.com/pages/Point-dEncre-France-Page-officielle/178099798924693'
        )
    );
    // On le redirige en JS (header PHP pas possible)
    echo ("<script>top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>");
```

**BUT to redirect users into the canvas app** i must use

```
header('location:xxx.php')
```

and not

```
<script>top.location.href="xxxx"</script>
```

otherwise FB redirect the user out of the canvas view.

And another tip : if you store the 'user id' into a db use a 'big int' column and not a 'int' column like i did!

Hope it will help people